# Speech recognition not working in ubuntu

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am starting a work which needs to convert audio into text. I am using the speechrecognition library of python. I saw a tutorial on github on how to use it. The program is not bale to recognise my voice through microphone.

I am using python 2.7 on ubuntu 16.04.

Code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Sphinx
try:
    print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

[github code link](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/microphone_recognition.py)

Output on terminal:

```
shivam@shivam-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Python/audio$ python temp.py
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Say something!
```

After, "Say something!", it keeps on blinking but my voice is not recognised.

[image: mic settings]
[image]

Comment: The alsa lines would suggest that it is unable to control the mixer and so. Perhaps you should tell the version of your operating system, version of Python and whether you're running this in ssh session, X11 terminal on local computer, or what.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7 and on terminal on local computer.

Comment: It did work for me, I said something and after some seconds it printed the output. I believe you've muted your microphone, and those ALSA warnings (which I got too) would mean that it tried to change the volume levels but failed; you should check both Ubuntu sound settings and alsamixer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I have attached the photo from my sound settings.

Comment: that's output, not input :P check the input tab.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : its input.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `PocketSphinx` module installed , running into issues.
But if I switch `recognize_sphinx` with `recognize_google`, its working for me.

Here is your modified code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Sphinx
try:
    #print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
    print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

Output

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Say something!
Sphinx thinks you said hello
>>>
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Now, even "say something" is not appearing on screen. I have pulseaudio and jack2 installed.